# Can I call variables or function from background page in Chrome Packaged App?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app

I have 2 JavasScript files for my Chrome Packaged App.
1. background.js is a main JavaScript file that called by manifest.json

```
var foo = 'sss';

function bar(a,b) {
    return a+b;
}

chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    bounds: {
      width: 500,
      height: 300
    }
  });
});
```

2. app.js is a controller of index.html

**Question:** Can I call variable "foo" or function "bar" from **background.js** in **app.js**?

**PS.** Or have any solution to transfer value between page such as **chrome.storage** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get data from a background page to the content script in google chrome extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700254/how-do-i-get-data-from-a-background-page-to-the-content-script-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 5):

In your app.js you can get the background page like this:

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(page) {
    page.foo;
    page.bar(2, 2);
});
```