# Chrome Extension Send Message From Background.js to Content Script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, content-script

I have read the documentation on how to do **Send Message From background javascript file(main.js) to Content Script (content.js)** but I cannot get the onMessage to open my alert.

**Manifest.json**

```
{
   "name": "Example",
   "version": "1.0.1",
   "manifest_version" : 2,
   "description": "Example Description",
   "background" : {
     "scripts" : ["main.js"]
   },
   "page_action" : {
      "default_icon": {
         "19": "icons/19.png",
         "38": "icons/38.png"
      },
      "default_title" : "Example Title"
   },
   "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js","scripts/content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "all_frames": false
   }],
   "permissions": [
       "tabs",
       "geolocation"
   ],
   "icons": {
       "16": "icons/16.png",
       "48": "icons/48.png",
       "128": "icons/48.png"
   }

}
```

**Background javascript file (main.js)**

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "SendIt"}, function(response) {});  
});
```

**Content javascript file (content.js)**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
   if (msg.action == 'SendIt') {
      alert("Message recieved!");
   }
});
```

Comment: I think you need to call it from your [popup.js and not from background](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11752341/1757620)

Comment: My guess would be that the background is sending the message before the content script is loaded.  Could you use your page action's onclick to send the message?

Comment: Teepeem's guess is very reasonable. Is the code displayed above all there is in `background.js` ? If not what triggers sending the message to the tab ?

Comment: Code in a background page is executed once (when Chrome starts up). When the background page has loaded, there's not any document that contains a content script. Hence you don't see any alert message.

Comment: I have given a plus to RobW and @Teepeeemm for there insight. I have added a trigger of tab load completion before sending the message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to the insight of @Teepeemm I have included a tab load complettion before sending message to content script.

**WAIT FOR TAB TO BE FULLY LOADED**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {          
   if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {   
      chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
         chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "SendIt"}, function(response) {});  
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Future programmers who find this should know that you shouldn't use a page action to do something on every page as soon as it's loaded; a browser action or content script would be better in that regard.  But I presume that in your case, you have an overactive page action because this is what your SSCCE ended up being.

Answer (score 0):

Sidenote: `chrome.extension.onMessage` is deprecated, you should be using `chrome.runtime.onMessage` - although I don't believe this will solve your problem.

I remember that I had an issue injecting a minified jquery file using content scripts. Try to use an un-minified version (ie jquery-1.8.3.js). Once you have done that, also add `jquery-1.8.3.js` to `web_accessible_resources` in your manifest file. (Read about that [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources.html))

If it still doesn't work, my last suggestion would be to add `"<all_urls>"` to the permissions array in your manifest.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the correct `chrome.runtime.onMessage`. -1 for saying it won't solve the problem (if it will depends on other things but that's not the point) -1 for suggesting minified version would cause a problem (there might be a problem if source-maps are missing but that is another story) -5 for suggesting `web_accessible_resources` which has nothing to do with the problem -10 for suggesting `<all_urls>` ! Totally unrelated and big mistake security-wise !

Answer (score 0):

If you have each script announce its presence (I prefer `console.log` to `alert`), you see that the background script runs once (on installation or startup), while the content script runs with each new page.  This means that you'll want to have some external event trigger the message.  Something like

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{action:"SendIt"});
});
```

And don't forget to call `chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);` as appropriate.